# Where is source for JAR files downloaded by Eclipse Maven plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I use Eclipse with Maven plugin. Where is the source for the JAR file downloaded using maven? I cannot find them in `.m2/repository`. I know they are downloaded since when I click on the class in Eclipse the source code showed up.

There are many posts which talked about how to download the source. But my problem is that I have the source but don't know where it is. I need to give the path when I use debugger. Though I can view the source code by clicking on the class, the debugger asked for the path.

Comment: Right click the file and see the Properties to see the file path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When maven downloads the sources it gets them all in a single jar file.

```
find ~/.m2/repository -name '*-sources.jar' 
...
/Users/steve/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/common/hibernate-commons-annotations/4.0.1.Final/hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.1.Final-sources.jar
/Users/steve/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/common/hibernate-commons-annotations/5.0.0.Final/hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.0.Final-sources.jar
/Users/steve/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/4.2.13.Final/hibernate-core-4.2.13.Final-sources.jar
/Users/steve/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/4.3.10.Final/hibernate-core-4.3.10.Final-sources.jar
/Users/steve/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/4.3.7.Final/hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final-sources.jar
/Users/steve/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/5.0.1.Final/hibernate-core-5.0.1.Final-sources.jar
...
```

You can point eclipse at one of these jars when it's looking for source files and it will grab them just fine.

Comment: I mean source code (.java) when I said source. No, the source ,java files are not part of .jar.

Comment: They are when maven downloads them, and eclipse displays them from the jar

Comment: You are right. Previously some source code is downloaded some are not. So I was a bit confused.